# PHP: Replace whitespace(s) at end of string before question mark_?

Tags: php

I have some users entering question titles like:

```
"Why do dogs die ?"
```

or even

```
"Why do dogs die   ?"
```

My goal is to remove the whitespaces before the question mark so that the output will be correct orthography:

```
"Why do dogs die?"
```

First I thought I could just search for `_?` and replace it with `?` but that would be prolbematic if there is a question such as:

```
"There is the sign ? - What is the name of it ?"
```

That's why I need to narrow it down to the end of the string.

Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$` at the end of regex.
Do `preg_replace('/\s+\?$/', '/?/', $string)`.
[Link to regex](https://regex101.com/r/tP6dN7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex,

```
[\t\s]+\?
```

this searches for a tab or space before a ?

so you can replace the space/tab with

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)
```

pattern would be `'/[\t\s]+\?/g'`

replacement would be `'?'`

Comment: Better to use `'` instead of `"`. Not a big deal, but it's always better to use `'` when you don't need `"` :P

Answer (score 0):

USE [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$var = "Why do dogs die ?";
preg_replace('/(\s+\?)/', '?',$var);
```